# TabbedPage con iconos en UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, uwp

Buen día, he tratado de colocar iconos a mi app UWP pero no me aparecen alguien me podría ayudar
cree un archivo styles
`

```
<local:IconConverter x:Key="IconConverter" />

<Style x:Key="TabbedPageStyle2" TargetType="uwp:FormsPivot">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}}" Width="15" Height="15" />
                    <TextBlock Name="TabbedPageHeaderTextBlock" Text="{Binding Title}"
                               Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

`
También el IconConverter

```
 public class IconConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value != null && value is Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource)
            return ((Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource)value).File;

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Y agrege esta linea en el app

```
 ((Style)this.Resources["TabbedPageStyle"]).Setters[0] = ((Style)this.Resources["TabbedPageStyle2"]).Setters[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema que tenia es que no le estaba poniendo la extensión de la imagen.`TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="Dlp.CustomerApps.MainPage"
            BarBackgroundColor ="#2196F3"
            BarTextColor="#ffffff"

```
        >
```

`
Para Andorid no es necesario la extensión del archivo para UWP si.